# How to receive image file from .NET API and display it in Dart Flutter app?

Tags: c#, flutter

I receive an image file as a byte String from a .NET Core API in my Dart Flutter app. Then I encode the `String` into a `List<int>`. I pass the `List<int>` to `Image.memory()` but the image does not appear and no exceptions are thrown.

This is for displaying images loaded from a .NET Core API in a Dart Flutter app. I have already tried `utf8.encode()`, `String.runes` and `String.codeUnits` (utf-16). But none work when I pass the `List<int>` to `Image.memory()`.

The Dart Flutter model class using `fromJson()` method encoding the image byte String in the JSON received from the .NET API:

```
class SelfMonitorPhotoModel {


  String id;
  String name;
  List<int> bytes;
  SelfMonitorPhotoMetaData metaData;

  SelfMonitorPhotoModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.bytes,
    this.metaData
  });


  factory SelfMonitorPhotoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var bytesString = json["bytes"] as String;
    List<int> bytesList = utf8.encode(bytesString);
    print(bytesList);

    return SelfMonitorPhotoModel(
      id: json["id"],
      bytes: bytesList,
      metaData: SelfMonitorPhotoMetaData.fromJson(json["metaData"]),
      name: json["name"]
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Id": id,
    "Name": name,
    "MetaData": metaData,
    "bytes": bytes
      };

}
```

Trying to display the bytes as an image with `Image.memory()`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    displayHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: displayHeight * 0.025),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Spacer(flex: 1),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 18,
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(displayWidth * 0.025)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: displayWidth * 0.05,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                                  offset: Offset(displayWidth * 0.01,
                                      displayWidth * 0.025))
                            ]),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(displayWidth * 0.025)),
                            child: Image.memory(
                              widget.photo.bytes
                            ))),
                  ),
                  Spacer(flex: 1),
                ]),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

The image file bytes are of type `byte[]`in the C# .NET API code, which is written as a String in the JSON:

```
// Controller action returning the photo/ image model.
[HttpGet("Photos/TaskId/{taskId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPhotosByTaskId(string taskId)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(await _selfMonitorService.GetPhotosByTaskId(taskId));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error($"{e.Message} | {e.StackTrace}");
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

// The model class returned from the API containing the image file bytes.
public class SelfMonitorPhotoModel
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
        public SelfMonitorPhotoMetaData MetaData { get; set; }

    }
```

I expect the image to be displayed in the Dart Flutter app. But it does not display and no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Provide http response in a raw form so that we can understand if it is about the output etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this blog](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/22/byte-arrays-and-asp-net-core-web-apis.aspx), .NET will encode the byte array in base64 inside the json.

Try replacing:

```
var bytesString = json["bytes"] as String;
List<int> bytesList = utf8.encode(bytesString);
```

with

```
var bytesString = json['bytes'] as String;
List<int> bytesList = base64.decode(bytesString);
```